# I need to pick highest NPA_TIME_ZONE_COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using this query in Oracle.

```
SELECT /*+parallel (reject,4) */ 
distinct n.rowid as npanxx_row_id, r.rating_orignum_used, n.npa, n.nxx, npanxx_effdate, n.line_range_from_number, n.line_range_to_number, n.city, n.state, n.country, n.country_code, n.ocn, n.lata, n.clli_code, n.stepcode, n.juris, n.time_zone as current_time_zone--, x.time_zone as npanxx_timezone, x2.time_zone as npa_timezone, case when x.time_zone >= '1' then x.time_zone else x2.time_zone end new_time_zone, count(x2.time_zone) as npa_time_zone_count
from npanxx n

left join npanxx x
on n.npa = x.npa and (substr(n.nxx, 1,1) = substr(x.nxx,1,1))
and x.time_zone is not null and x.time_zone <> '0'

left join npanxx x2
on n.npa = x2.npa 
and x2.time_zone is not null and x2.time_zone <> '0'

inner join reject r
on substr(r.rating_orignum_used,1,3) = n.npa and substr(r.rating_orignum_used,4,3) = n.nxx and substr(r.rating_orignum_used, 7,1) = substr(n.line_range_from_number,1,1)

where 
n.npanxx_effdate = (select max(sub.npanxx_effdate) from npanxx sub where n.npa=sub.npa and n.nxx = sub.nxx and n.line_range_from_number = sub.line_range_from_number)
and r.carrier = 'LEVEL3' and r.error_code = '309' and r.rowid in ('AAQBSyAKKAABZ7yAAJ')and trunc(r.processdate) >= trunc(sysdate-90)

group by n.rowid, r.rating_orignum_used, n.npa, n.nxx, n.npanxx_effdate, n.line_range_from_number, n.line_range_to_number, n.city, n.state, n.country, n.country_code, n.ocn, n.lata, n.clli_code, n.stepcode, n.juris, n.time_zone, x.time_zone , x2.time_zone
```

By running this query I get the result

```
NPANXX_ROW_ID          .....     npa_time_zone_count
AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy                   3780
AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy                    10
```

and I need one row with the highest count so it come as

```
   NPANXX_ROW_ID         .....          npa_time_zone_count
 AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy                            3780
```

I used HAVING statement but its just giving me error
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = (
      SELECT
         MAX(count(x2.time_zone))
      FROM
         npanxx inner
      WHERE
         inner.time_zone IS NOT NULL AND
         inner.time_zone <> 0 AND
         npa = inner.npa
         and x2.NXX = INNER.NXX
      GROUP BY
         inner.state,
         inner.country,
         inner.time_zone)
```

Comment: Including the actual error might be useful to those who would try to help you.

Comment: @Tom H, ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.
This is the error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` to number rows and pick the highest, int this way:

```
WITH subquery AS
(
    /* your complex query goes here */
     SELECT 'AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy' as NPANXX_ROW_ID, '....' As "....", 3780 As npa_time_zone_count 
     FROM dual
     Union All
     SELECT 'AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy' as NPANXX_ROW_ID, '....' As "....", 10 As npa_time_zone_count 
     FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by NPANXX_ROW_ID 
                                ORDER BY npa_time_zone_count DESC ) rn
      FROM subquery t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
======================================================
NPANXX_ROW_ID      .... NPA_TIME_ZONE_COUNT         RN
------------------ ---- ------------------- ----------
AABWcFABmAAAxMrAAy ....                3780          1
```

Comment: Thank you its working but I have many different npanxx_row_ids which has duplicates will it work if I don't have any hard code npanxx_row_ids??